# Awesomium C# | Need Help getting an random Element from many Elements

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser-control, element, awesomium

In this code I got the amount of all persons. This worked.
Now I want to get one random person from all person, but this doesn't work. I get an `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException` at the line `using (person)`
Sorry for my English.

Here the code:

```
dynamic document = (JSObject)webControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByClassName(\"badge\")[1]");
using (document)
{
    string gg = document.innerHTML;
    personcount = Convert.ToInt16(gg);
}

int selectperson = rnd.Next(0, personcount-1);

dynamic document2 = (JSObject)webControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByTagName('a')");
using (document2)
{
    dynamic person = document2.getElementByClassName("name")[selectperson];
    using (person)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(person.innerText);
    }
}
```

and here is the HTML Tag from an example person:

```
<a class="name" href="http://kontakt-4.dastelefonbuch.de/Neuwied/Martin-Kaiser-Neuwied-Feldkircher-Str.html" rel="nofollow">
```

Comment: Is it possible that the object person is actually empty?

Comment: I just made the MessageBox.Show(); for Test
I want to click it !
But i get an Exception Error. And its of course not empty :/

Comment: Your second call to *`ExecuteJavascriptWithResult`* passes *`document.getElementsByTagName('a')`* so it returns a *`NodeList`*, not the page's *`document`* object. Therefore you cannot call *`getElementByClassName`* on *`document2`*.

Several questions:

1. What is the version Awesomium you use?
2. Where is this code executed? (like, is it inside a view's event handler and which event)
3. What is the message of the `RuntimeBinderException`?

Comment: private void Awesomium_Windows_Forms_WebControl_LoadingFrameComplete_2(object sender, FrameEventArgs e){...} <- Its in there.
The message from Exception is : {"Der Awesomium.Core.JSValue-Typ kann nicht implizit in System.IDisposable konvertiert werden."}.
I only have it in german language sorry.
And where can I look which Awesomium Version I have?

Comment: I have Awesomium Version: awesomium_1_7_5_1_sdk_win

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt found out how I can do this. But i found another way now everything is working thanks! :)

```
                dynamic document = (JSObject)webControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByClassName(\"badge\")[1]");
                string gg = document.innerText;
                personcount = Convert.ToInt16(gg);

                int odd = rnd.Next(1, personcount * 2);
                for (int i = 0;odd % 2 == 0;i++)
                {
                    odd = rnd.Next(1, personcount * 2);
                }
                dynamic document2 = (JSObject)webControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByClassName('name')["+odd+"]");
                using (document2)
                {
                    if (document2.HasMethod("click"))
                    {
                        document2.Invoke("click");
                        stepcount = 2;
                    }
                }
```